# HP Slate 21 Won't Boot and Recovery Doesn't Work

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, recovery-mode, bootloader

My stock HP Slate no longer boots.  It stops at the HP logo / Powered by Android splash screen.  I've tried all of the solutions typically available to this device like resetting with the power turned off button combination.  I've tried all the options (start, Recovery Mode and Restart BootLoader) but they all freeze on the same splash screen.

I now have a really nice brick.  Any suggestions / recommendations on what I can do to restore or recover this device?

Comment: Did you try flashing it ?

Comment: I've not found any image or instructions on how to accomplish that.  So, not yet.

Comment: Try official website: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Operating-Systems-and-Recovery/How-to-re-install-Android-on-HP-Slate-21-when-everything-was/td-p/4561986

Comment: Reported at https://community.hpe.com/t5/General-Feedback-and-Suggestions/Cannot-boot-up-hp-slate-pro-21/td-p/6972218

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you unplug it, plug it back in and hit the power button it will boot. But, any time you shutdown again and try to restart, same boot issue persists. Unplug, plugin, power on, repeat...